# 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded' for Neural Net in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to train a neural net to produce a synthetic image of a cat. I'm currently getting this error and it's the first time I've seen it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gan10.py", line 43, in loadImages
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = loadImages()
  File "gan10.py", line 43, in loadImages
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = loadImages()
  File "gan10.py", line 43, in loadImages
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = loadImages()
  [Previous line repeated 997 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This first line is line 43:

```
def loadImages():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = loadImages()
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5)/127.5
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    return (x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test)
```

Do I need to rewrite this iteratively rather than recursively? I have already tried to set a new recursion limit with:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

This did not appear to do anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I need to rewrite this iteratively rather than recursively?

No, you need to fix your logic:

```
def loadImages():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = loadImages()
```

This is an infinite loop, the function `loadImages()` is calling itself without an exit condition.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Hope you didn't facepalm too hard answering that! :D

Can you please explain what code should follow instead of loadImages?

"(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = train_test_split" produces the exception: "local variable 'x_train' referenced before assignment". 

I'm brand new so I'm trying to work things out.

Comment: @Darren It's not a bad idea to try to write this iteratively, maybe it'll be easier. If not, then ask yourself, how do I know that I need to stop loading images? that's the base case, and you should check for it at the start, with an if/else . Regarding the other error, I don't know what's `train_test_split`, but from the looks of it, it should return a list of two tuples, each one with two elements - something like this: `[(1, 2), (3, 4)]`

Comment: Another way to see it - what should be the initial value of `x_train`? that's the value that seems to be defined in terms of itself, but at some point you _must_ know how to initialise it, that's the base case of the recursion. And what are the initial values for `x_test` and `y_test`? and why `y_train` never changes?

Comment: Hi Oscar. 

I'm basing this line off another line of code which loads the mnist data:

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

All I know is this worked with the MNIST handwritten digits and I'd like to load and train my own data rather than using this database. I still don't understand a lot of the technical aspects of machine learning and programming even though I am trying to.

Comment: The problem is not related to machine learning, and you should study a bit about recursive algorithms before proceeding. Sorry, but I can't help much more, as I'm not familiar with the problem you're trying to solve. One final thought: maybe write a separate loading function? and call it in the first line.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and thoughts! I'm not sure what loading function I should be using but I'll keep at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191937/discussion-between-darren-and-oscar-lopez).